OptaPlanner org package not recognized when using OptaPy
I need to use OptaPlanners SolverEventListener using OptaPy.I am able to import org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.event which has this class and also seeing the methods when writing code but on running it throws the following error.
from org.optaplanner.core.api.solver import SolverFactory ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'
I am new to OptaPy so trying to see what I am missing.
I am trying to see if I can explicitly import OptaPlanner modules. I am using PyCharm for my OptaPy solution development.
